# Codename one BrowserComponent setBrowserNavigationCallback

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to use the

> setBrowserNavigationCallback

method of the BrowserComponent to call a java method from the html page.

This is what I have in java:

```
            map_browser = (BrowserComponent) this.getInternal();                
            map_browser.setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback() {                    
                public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
                    System.out.println("in here::" + url);
                    if (url.startsWith("http://getproperties")) {
                        System.out.println("get properties from java code 1");                            
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

The code on html is:

```
 <a href="http://getproperties">Load</a>
```

This works fine. When I click on Load, the shouldNavigate() gets invoked.

However, this works only once. If I click on Load again, nothing happens...

Is this the expected behavior ?

If yes, what is the best way to achieve calling a java function multiple times from javascript ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

BR,
Sanket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This causes the location for the browser to change which then means that further navigation won't occur. Try using myprotocol://getproperties which won't go into the location of the browser and should be fired repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I have ended up using JSFunction. Works like a charm